# Excel Conditional Format depending on two cells, two conditions

Tags: excel, colors, background, format, conditional-statements

I would like to format a cell (so that the background colour is yellow) when in this cell it contains "mid" as text and in another cell in the column next to it it contains "installation".

Can you explain to me how I can do this? Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards, 
question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've neglected to mention which of the columns would possibly contain either of the two words but let's say you are looking for *mid* in column C and *installation* in column H. To color the cells in column C that meet both criteria, first select all of column C with C1 as the `Active Cell` then create a conditional formatting rule using the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* option and supply the following for *Format cells where this formula is true:*

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mid", $C1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("installation", $H1)))
```

Click Format and select a yellow *Fill* then click OK to accept the format and OK once again to create the new CF rule.

*Addendum:*

Adjusted to look for *mid* in column H and *installation* in column N, the CF rule formula would be,

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mid", $H1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("installation", $N1)))
```

Prior to creating the new rule, clear out any previous attempts with *Home, Conditional Formatting, Clear Rules* then tap `F5` (aka `GoTo`) and type `N:N,H:H` in the *Reference:* box and click OK. This should select columns H and N with H1 as the `Active Cell`. Create the rule based on the formula above and you should receive results like the following.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your quick response. Unfortunately it`s not working.

Comment: I've followed your instructions. But the cells which contain "mid" in the column H and as well "installation" in column N don't turn yellow. Do you have an explanation? @Jeeped

Comment: @question - You never actually specified which columns were to be looked at. I had to make up some columns to use as an example and hope that you could transcribe the offered solution for your own purposes. For column H containing *mid* and column N containing *installation* you would use the following adaptation:
`=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mid", $H1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("installation", $N1)))`
Prior to creating the rule, tap F5 then type `N:N,H:H` into the *Reference:* box and click OK. That will set up the correct range selection for creating the CF rule.

Comment: I adapted the formula. Yet, it is not working. :( I don't know what I do wrong. Do you have any idea? @question

Comment: What I forgot to tell you: I only want to have the cell with "mid" with yellow background. Not the one with "installation". Is that possible? Right now nothing turns yellow.

Comment: @question - a) If you only want column H to show the yellow fill then tap F5 and type H:H instead of N:N,H:H. b) Did you clear all previous attempts at CF Rule formatting (as directed to within the Answer)?